# .NET (C#) "Could not load file or assembly" to version 9 when all my projects are referencing version 7

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager, system.configuration

My main UI project uses two other dependencies loaded into the solution which call System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager versions 7.0.0, yet every time I compile I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=9.0.0.0". I previously had updated that NuGet package to 9 but rolled it back thinking that it was causing conflicts with other code. Now I'm not able to use with 7 either...

I've tried the ChatGPT solutions: Check Project References, Check App.Config or Web.Config, and Check for Other Assembly References. But could not find any projects which reference 9 or App.config files referencing 9 explicitly.

In my App.Config file I have these configSections, would that potentially create a version conflict?

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="ATSMainUI.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: The error means you have a `PackageReference` in a csproj file that refers to the 9 preview version. .NET 7 and 9 are .NET *Core* versions. They don't use app.config *at all*. `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is a legacy compatibility package only meant to ease migration to .NET Core. The latest stable version is 8.0 which targets .NET 6 and later.

Comment: BTW .NET 7 reaches End Of Life in 2 weeks. It's time to upgrade to .NET 8 *and* stop using `app.config`

Comment: Okay, that does help me wrap my head around it a bit more. I'm using .NET 6 and targeting Win7. Maybe if I just remove all the dependencies for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager? It wasn't clear to me to begin with why it's even there.

Comment: Removing this assemblyBinding fixed it:
 <!--<runtime> 
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>-->